# Symfony Workflow versus custom form validator

Tags: forms, symfony, validation, architecture, workflow

I started looking around [Symfony Workflow component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/workflow.html). Great possibilities to guide object lifecycle changes.

Workflow are object-related only. **How to efficiently link this with form feedback?** Without workflow, I would give a go **for [custom validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html) where I can put a check logic** (possibly stored in a service to reuse them elsewhere) and then stop things if criterias don't match what's requested.

Should I trigger workflow transitions within custom form validators? If not, which architecture should I use here?